# Optimising My MySQL Query

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

I'm creating a forum, and needed a little feedback. I've been programming for a long time, but I'm fairly knew to MySQL, and wondered if I'm doing this correctly.

This is the query I'm using to output thr topic index of a selected forum. I'm trying to collect all the information in a single query, as opposed to only collecting the topic info, and then collecting the post and member info once in every in every loop, totaling to 35 individual queries(*one for each topic*). Is that clear?

Basically, it works. It's a bit slow (*approximately 1 second*) even with only 300-400 topics.

I've used profiling, and gathered that the most time consuming actions are:
Copying to tmp table: 0.538037
Sending data: 0.206218
Copying to group table: 0.137549

Edit:
The query will be run once each time someone enters the page(about 200-300 times an hour judging by site activity). I intend to retrieve about 4000-5000 rows at a time.

My question is: Is this the best method? Is there anything I could do to optimise this query? Or Would I be better off having lots of smaller queries executed inside a loop?

```
$user_id: id of the user
$forum_id: id of the selected forum


SELECT
  # Topic records
  `topics`.*,

  # First Post
  GROUP_CONCAT(`posts`.`id`) AS `post_id`, # All post ids
  `posts`.`post`    AS `post_first_msg`,
  `posts`.`date`    AS `post_first_date`,
  `posts`.`member`  AS `post_first_member`,

  # First member
  `members`.`id` AS `member_id`,
  `members`.`username` AS member_username,

  # Returns last 3 members' id
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(
    GROUP_CONCAT(`members`.`id` ORDER BY `posts`.`date` DESC SEPARATOR '\\\\'), '\\\\', 3
  ) AS member_last_id,

  # Returns last 3 members' username
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(
    GROUP_CONCAT(`members`.`username` ORDER BY `posts`.`date` DESC SEPARATOR '\\\\'), '\\\\', 3
  ) AS member_last_username,

  # Get last viewed topic id
  `member_topic_lastview`.`lastview` AS `lastview`

FROM
  `topics`

# Returns the `posts` table in ASC order
JOIN (
  SELECT *
  FROM `posts`
  ORDER BY `posts`.`date` ASC
) AS `posts` ON `posts`.`topic` = `topics`.`id`

# Member table, only the columns needed
JOIN (
  SELECT
    `members`.`id`,
    `members`.`username`
FROM `members`
) AS `members` ON `members`.`id` = `posts`.`member`

# Forum table, containing the forum info
LEFT JOIN `forum` ON `forum`.`id` = `topics`.`forum`

# Table containing the latest viewed post id of each topic
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT *
  FROM `member_topic_lastview`
    WHERE `member_topic_lastview`.`member` = '$user_id'
) AS `member_topic_lastview` ON `member_topic_lastview`.`topic` = `topics`.`id`

WHERE
  `forum` > $forum_id

GROUP BY
  `topics`.`id`

ORDER BY
  `topics`.`sticky` DESC,
  MAX(`posts`.`date`) DESC

LIMIT 35
```

**Thank you very much!**

Comment: How often does this query need to be run? How much data are you intending to query?

Comment: What kind of indexes do you have on the various tables?

Comment: The query will be run once each time someone enters the page(about 200-300 times an hour judging by site activity). I intend to retrieve about 4000-5000 rows at a time. I can find out the size if you like.

Comment: @Melanie: I'm not using indexes. Should I be?

Comment: Yes, I would suggest indexes on at least some of the tables. It depends on the size of the tables, but you should look at that. If you're not familiar with indexes, take a look here: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Indexing/68439/

Comment: @Melanie: Thank you! I'll take a look at that and try to implement it. :)

Answer (score 2):

The first thing to do is look at your explain plan and post that.  The other thing that stands out is that you don't really want to do a lot of sub-queries.

Just to give a start, looking at your first join

```
FROM
  `topics`

# Returns the `posts` table in ASC order
JOIN (
  SELECT *
  FROM `posts`
  ORDER BY `posts`.`date` ASC
) AS `posts` ON `posts`.`topic` = `topics`.`id`
```

This is probably going to be much faster if you just write it like:

```
FROM
  `topics`

# Returns the `posts` table in ASC order
JOIN `posts` ON `posts`.`topic` = `topics`.`id`
```

Comment: Thanks. But I need to retrieve the posts table in order of date, and this is the only way I know how.

Comment: Then do `ORDER BY posts.date ASC` at the very end of the query?

Comment: @TomMcPadden - Your best bet is to get a raw list of all the data you want and then wrap that in another query.  If you could post some sample tables and data into http://www.sqlfiddle.com, as well as the expected results, I can give you better suggestions.

Comment: @BrianHoover: Thank you! This is the structure of the four tables in use: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8b37b
The expected results? Can I do that for you on SQL Fiddle?

Comment: @Patashu: Thanks, but no. That doesn't work. My topics will be orginised wrongly.

Comment: @TomMcPadden - Could you also post some data in the "Build Schema?"

Comment: @BrianHoover: SQL Fiddle won't allow me to insert enough date. I can only insert 8000 characters woth of code, which is only enough to insert a couple of posts/topics. Is there any way around that?

Comment: @TomMcPadden - If you can just post some records, along with what you would like to see from those records, that would be enough.

Comment: @BrianHoover: Oh I see. Sorry for the hassle! This is exactly what I'm aiming for: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/91ad79/1

Comment: I'm impressed that it's working.  Do you have to get all this data in one query?  I suspect that, for what you are doing, it's about as quick as it's going to be.  Be careful with group_concats, because they have a character limit.

Comment: @BrianHoover: I know, it looks a bit overkill and messy. But the only  alternative is having lots of small queries inside a loop... which seems less beneficial. And I've increased the limit to group_concat too. I guess there's nothing I can do to improve it. Thanks for your help anyway! :)